# Documentation for Nokia E52 home screen plugin programming

Tags: documentation, plugins, nokia, homescreen

I don't seem to find any documentation on how to implement an home screen plugin for Nokia E52 devices.

Does someone know how to do this or where this documentation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Active Idle Plugin API is not publicly available. You can get hold of it through [Forum Nokia's API partnering program](http://www.forum.nokia.com/I_Want_To/Develop_Mobile_Applications/Technical_Support/). Even then you basically need a custom firmware build as the [plugins can only be loaded from ROM](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/KIS001196_-_Restrictions_in_developing_customised_Active_Idle_plug-ins). However, there are some [hints](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=156321) that the strict ROM only policy could have been relaxed in S60 3.2 that E52 is running but I was unable to find any specific public information.